# Generate simulated data in Python while meeting a range of correlations with respect to a predefined variable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, simulation

Let's denote refVar, a variable of interest that contains experimental data.
For the simulation study, I would like to generate other variables V0.05, V0.10, V0.15 until V0.95.
Note that for the variable name, the value following V represents the correlation between the variable and refVar (in order to quick track in the final dataframe).
My readings led me to multivariate_normal() from numpy. However, when using this function, it generates 2 1D-arrays both with random numbers. What I want is to always keep refVar and generate other arrays filled with random numbers, while meeting the specified correlation.
Please, find below my my code. To cut it short, I've no clue how to generate other variables relative to my experimental variable refVar. Ideally, I would like to build a data frame containing the following columns: refVar,V0.05,V0.10,...,V0.95. I hope you get my point and thank you in advance for your time

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import multivariate_normal as mvn

refVar = [75.25,77.93,78.2,61.77,80.88,71.95,79.88,65.53,85.03,61.72,60.96,56.36,23.16,73.36,64.18,83.07,63.25,49.3,78.2,30.96]
mean_refVar = np.mean(refVar)
for r in np.arange(0,1,0.05):
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 1
    cov = r 
    cov_matrix = [[var1,cov],
                 [cov,var2]]
    data = mvn([mean_refVar,mean_refVar],cov_matrix,size=len(refVar))
    output = 'corr_'+str(r.round(2))+'.txt'
    df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['refVar','v'+str(r.round(2)])
    df.to_csv(output,sep='\t',index=False) # Ideally, instead of creating an output for each correlation, I would like to generate a DF with refVar and all these newly created Series
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65895382/generate-simulated-data-in-python-while-meeting-a-range-of-correlations-with-res) we can generate the sequence as follow:

```
def rand_with_corr(refVar, corr):
    # center and normalize refVar
    X = np.array(refVar) - np.mean(refVar)
    X = X/np.linalg.norm(X)

    # random sampling Y
    Y = np.random.rand(len(X))
    # centralize Y
    Y = Y - Y.mean()
    
    # find the orthorgonal component to X
    Y = Y - Y.dot(X) * X
    
    # normalize Y
    Y = Y/np.linalg.norm(Y)


    # output
    return Y + (1/np.tan(np.arccos(corr))) * X

# test
out = rand_with_corr(refVar, 0.05)

pd.Series(out).corr(pd.Series(refVar))
# out
# 0.050000000000000086
```

Comment: You nailed it Quang. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi Quang, The function you wrote does generate an array of random values with regards to the specified correlation, which is good. However, it sounds like they fall in the range of -1 to 1, certainly because the variable was centered and normalized. Is there a way to get values more like the experimental data (refVar) or falling in certain range? Thank you again for taking the time to look into it. I really appreciate.